# Implement Java Iterator and Iterable in same class?

Tags: java, iterator, iterable

I am trying to understand Java `Iterator` and `Iterable` interfaces

I am writing this class

```
class MyClass implements Iterable<String> {
    public String[] a = null;
    public MyClass(String[] arr) {
        a = arr;    
    }

    public MyClassIterator iterator() {
        return new MyClassIterator(this);
    }

    public class MyClassIterator implements Iterator<String> {
        private MyClass myclass = null;
        private int count = 0;
        public MyClassIterator(MyClass m) {
            myclass = m;    
        }

        public boolean hasNext() {
            return count < myclass.a.length;
        }
        public String next() {
            int t = count;
            count++;
            return myclass.a[t];
        }

        public void remove() {
            throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
        }
    }   
}
```

It seems to be working.

Should I have:

```
Myclass implements Iterable<Stirng>, Iterator<String> {

}
```

Or I should put `MyClassIterator` outside `MyClass` as

```
class MyClass implements Iterable<String> {
    public String[] a = null;
    public MyClass(String[] arr) {
        a = arr;    
    }
    public MyClassIterator iterator() {
        return new MyClassIterator(this);
    }
}


    public class MyClassIterator implements Iterator<String> {
        private MyClass myclass = null;
        private int count = 0;
        public MyClassIterator(MyClass m) {
            myclass = m;    
        }

        public boolean hasNext() {
            return count < myclass.a.length;
        }
        public String next() {
            int t = count;
            count++;
            return myclass.a[t];
        }

        public void remove() {
            throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
        }
    }
```

Which one is better?

Comment: Why does your class need to do both? In general you would implement Iterable so someone can get an Iterator from your class.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

You should almost *never* implement both `Iterable` and `Iterator` in the same class. They do different things. An iterator is naturally *stateful* - as you iterate using it, it has to update its view of the world. An iterable, however, only needs to be able to create new iterators. In particular, you could have several iterators working over the same original iterable at the same time.

Your current approach is pretty much okay - there are aspects of the implementation I'd change, but it's fine in terms of the separation of responsibilities.

Comment: thanks, i updated a bit my question, which one is better, how about put MyClassInterator outside MyClass?

Comment: @icn: Keeping MyClassIterator as a nested class is fine. (Iterator though, not Interator.) I suggest you make it a private static final class though. You don't need to be able to refer to it directly from anywhere else, after all.

Comment: @icn: You should keep `MyClassIterator` inside `MyClass`. You should also make it `private` and make the method return `Iterator<String>`. You should also not pass in `MyClass` to the constructor because `MyClassIterator` is an inner class and has an implicit reference to the surrounding instance of `MyClass`, so you can just access the array `a` directly in it.

Comment: @Jon - why would you make the inner class static?

Comment: @Stephen: you're not using the implicit reference to an instance of the outer class, so why *not* make it static?

Comment: @Jon: `Iterator`s are often (including in this case) perfect for non-static inner classes though. He's not using the implicit reference to the outer class but... he should be! =)

Comment: @Jon - ah, in general I'd certainly agree with that philosophy, but in this case I think it makes sense to instead get rid of the constructor which takes `MyClass` and go ahead and use the implicit reference.

Comment: @Stephen: that would certainly work too. Personally I'm not a fan of the implicit reference to start with. Awkward syntax, and too easy to forget it's there. Just my personal preference though :)

Answer (score 9):

You were on track with your first try. `MyClass` only needs to implement `Iterable<String>`, which in turn requires you to provide an `Iterator<String>` implementation to return from `Iterable<String>.iterator()`.

There's no need to put the `MyClassIterator` outside of `MyClass` because in most cases you will never even need to directly use the `Iterator<String>` (it's used implicitly by the `for .. in ..` syntax on `Iterable<String>`s), and in all other cases the interface is sufficient unless you actually add additional behavior to the implementation (which you likely won't ever need to do).

Here's how I'd do it, see comments inlined:

```
import java.util.Iterator;

class MyClass implements Iterable<String>{
    public String[] a=null; //make this final if you can
    public MyClass(String[] arr){
        a=arr; //maybe you should copy this array, for fear of external modification
    }

    //the interface is sufficient here, the outside world doesn't need to know
    //about your concrete implementation.
    public Iterator<String> iterator(){
        //no point implementing a whole class for something only used once
        return new Iterator<String>() {
            private int count=0;
            //no need to have constructor which takes MyClass, (non-static) inner class has access to instance members
            public boolean hasNext(){
                //simplify
                return count < a.length;
            }
            public String next(){
                return a[count++]; //getting clever
            }

            public void remove(){
                throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
            }
        };
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, since we have a exception "throw new UnsupportedOperationException();", somewhere in the program we should specify that an excepriton to be throwed something like throw  UnsupportedOperationException()?

Comment: Your welcome, @icn. Yes, it's probably sufficient to just mention it in the comments for `iterator()`. In practice it won't matter, `for .. in ..` is pretty much the only construct which makes direct use of `Iterator`s in (modern) Java and it doesn't attempt to use `remove`. Indeed, "optional" interface members such as `remove` are  useless at best since consumers pretty much have to assume they will throw.

Answer (score 2):

You should not do `Myclass implements Iterable<String>,Iterator<String>{` since iterators are single-use.  With the exception of list iterators, there's no way to return them to the start.

Incidentally, you can skip the

```
MyClass myClass;
public MyClassInterator(MyClass m){
  myclass=m;  
}
```

and instead of referencing

```
myClass
```

reference

```
MyClass.this
```

Your inner class is not static, so `MyClass.this` will reference the instance of the enclosing class that created it.