# Bit mask generation to minimize number of 1

Tags: java, algorithm, loops

In order to explore some solutions, I need to generate all possibilities. I'm doing it by using bit masking, like this:

```
for (long i = 0; i < 1L << NB; i++) {
    System.out.println(Long.toBinaryString(i));
    if(checkSolution(i)) {
        this.add(i); // add i to solutions
    }
}
this.getBest(); // get the solution with lowest number of 1
```

this allow me to explore (if NB=3):

```
000
001
010
011
100
101
110
111
```

My problem is that the best solution is the one with the lowest number of 1.
So, in order to stop the search as soon as I found a solution, I would like to have a different order and produce something like this:

```
000
001
010
100
011
101
110
111
```

That would make the search a lot faster since I could stop as soon as I get the first solution. But I don't know how can I change my loop to get this output...

PS: NB is undefined...

Comment: @FilipeGonçalves: Are you trying to tell us that `(0b011 + 1) > (1<<3)` i.e. `4 > 8`?

Comment: @fabian Nevermind, I was clearly wrong. I just thought of `1 << 3` as `100`, my bad.

Comment: why you are using longs? if an integer isnt sufficient than you have a very very long calculation time, so I advise you to use integers

Comment: @martijnn2008 The size of the mask can be 60 but with a solution containing only 3 bits set to one. In this case, I need a long to represent the mask and I need to order my search so that I can find this solution faster. Determining an upper bounds for the number of ones in the mask is another matter ;)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The idea is to turn your loop into two nested loops; the outer loop sets the number of 1's, and the inner loop iterates through every combination of binary numbers with N 1's. Thus, your loop becomes:

```
for (long i = 1; i < (1L << NB); i = (i << 1) | 1) {
  long j = i;
  do {
    System.out.println(Long.toBinaryString(j));
    if(checkSolution(j)) {
        this.add(j); // add j to solutions
    }
    j = next_of_n(j);
  } while (j < (1L << NB));
}
```

`next_of_n()` is defined as:

```
long next_of_n(long j) {
  long smallest, ripple, new_smallest, ones;
  if (j == 0)
    return j;
  smallest = (j & -j);
  ripple = j + smallest;
  new_smallest = (ripple & -ripple);
  ones = ((new_smallest / smallest) >> 1) - 1;
  return (ripple | ones);
}
```

The algorithm behind `next_of_n()` is described in *C: A Reference Manual, 5th edition*, section 7.6, while showing an example of a SET implementation using bitwise operations. It may be a little hard to understand the code at first, but here's what the book says about it:

> This code exploits many unusual properties of unsigned arithmetic. As
>   an illustration:

```
if x ==               001011001111000, then

smallest ==           000000000001000
ripple ==             001011010000000
new_smallest ==       000000010000000
ones ==               000000000000111
the returned value == 001011010000111
```

> The overall idea is that you find the rightmost contiguous group of
>   1-bits. Of that group, you slide the leftmost 1-bit to the left one
>   place, and slide all the others back to the extreme right. (This code
>   was adapted from HAKMEM.)

I can provide a deeper explanation if you still don't get it. Note that the algorithm assumes 2 complement, and that all arithmetic should ideally take place on unsigned integers, mainly because of the right shift operation. I'm not a huge Java guy, I tested this in C with `unsigned long` and it worked pretty well. I hope the same applies to Java, although there's no such thing as `unsigned long` in Java. As long as you use reasonable values for `NB`, there should be no problem.

Comment: There are no unsigned types in Java. If you need 32-bit unsigned, you must  "simulate" them with 64-bit `long`s and, if necessary, added masking.  This is a really annoying aspect of Java.

Comment: @Gene Yep, I know. It's a pain in the ass. That's why I said I hope it works in Java. But I think it shouldn't be a problem as long as `NB` is a reasonable value, i.e., something that doesn't hit the sign bit.

Comment: Is [this](http://graphics.stanford.edu/~seander/bithacks.html#NextBitPermutation) the same algorthm?

Comment: @OldCurmudgeon It looks the same to me, only slightly more obfuscated :p

Comment: @Gene You don't need to emulate anything, java uses twos-complement, meaning any basic operation you carry out (+, -, ~, <<, >>>) on a signed primitive will produce the same bit pattern as the corresponding unsigned type would have produced. You only need to be careful when using relational operators (>, >=, <, <=). For these flipping the top bit before the comparison gives the unsigned result. The main problem lies in not messing up on the programmers side.

Comment: @Durandal You must use a `long` if you want to represent 2^32-1 and an `int` if you want to represent 2^8-1.  That's all I was saying.

Answer (score 3):

This is an iterator that iterates bit patterns of the same cardinality.

```
/**
 * Iterates all bit patterns containing the specified number of bits.
 *
 * See "Compute the lexicographically next bit permutation"
 * http://graphics.stanford.edu/~seander/bithacks.html#NextBitPermutation
 *
 * @author OldCurmudgeon
 */
public class BitPattern implements Iterable<BigInteger> {
  // Useful stuff.
  private static final BigInteger ONE = BigInteger.ONE;
  private static final BigInteger TWO = ONE.add(ONE);
  // How many bits to work with.
  private final int bits;
  // Value to stop at. 2^max_bits.
  private final BigInteger stop;
  // Should we invert the output.
  private final boolean not;

  // All patterns of that many bits up to the specified number of bits - invberting if required.
  public BitPattern(int bits, int max, boolean not) {
    this.bits = bits;
    this.stop = TWO.pow(max);
    this.not = not;
  }

  // All patterns of that many bits up to the specified number of bits.
  public BitPattern(int bits, int max) {
    this(bits, max, false);
  }

  @Override
  public Iterator<BigInteger> iterator() {
    return new BitPatternIterator();
  }

  /*
   * From the link:
   * 
   * Suppose we have a pattern of N bits set to 1 in an integer and 
   * we want the next permutation of N 1 bits in a lexicographical sense. 
   * 
   * For example, if N is 3 and the bit pattern is 00010011, the next patterns would be 
   * 00010101, 00010110, 00011001,
   * 00011010, 00011100, 00100011, 
   * and so forth. 
   * 
   * The following is a fast way to compute the next permutation. 
   */
  private class BitPatternIterator implements Iterator<BigInteger> {
    // Next to deliver - initially 2^n - 1
    BigInteger next = TWO.pow(bits).subtract(ONE);
    // The last one we delivered.
    BigInteger last;

    @Override
    public boolean hasNext() {
      if (next == null) {
        // Next one!
        // t gets v's least significant 0 bits set to 1
        // unsigned int t = v | (v - 1); 
        BigInteger t = last.or(last.subtract(BigInteger.ONE));
        // Silly optimisation.
        BigInteger notT = t.not();
        // Next set to 1 the most significant bit to change, 
        // set to 0 the least significant ones, and add the necessary 1 bits.
        // w = (t + 1) | (((~t & -~t) - 1) >> (__builtin_ctz(v) + 1));
        // The __builtin_ctz(v) GNU C compiler intrinsic for x86 CPUs returns the number of trailing zeros.
        next = t.add(ONE).or(notT.and(notT.negate()).subtract(ONE).shiftRight(last.getLowestSetBit() + 1));
        if (next.compareTo(stop) >= 0) {
          // Dont go there.
          next = null;
        }
      }
      return next != null;
    }

    @Override
    public BigInteger next() {
      last = hasNext() ? next : null;
      next = null;
      return not ? last.not(): last;
    }

    @Override
    public void remove() {
      throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported.");
    }

    @Override
    public String toString () {
      return next != null ? next.toString(2) : last != null ? last.toString(2): "";
    }

  }

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println("BitPattern(3, 10)");
    for (BigInteger i : new BitPattern(3, 10)) {
      System.out.println(i.toString(2));
    }
  }

}
```

Comment: I like the original ideas of creating an Iterator and using BigInteger! That's clever. One question: Why did you create a private class instead of making `public class BitPattern implements Iterable<BigInteger>, Iterator<BigInteger>` ?

Comment: @ncenerar - Implementing both `Iterable` and `Iterator` is bad practice as `Iterable.iterator()` can be called twice. This way is also easier. See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5836220/823393) for the main reasons.

Answer (score 2):

First you loop over your number of ones, say n. First you start with 2^n-1, which is the first integer to contain exactly n ones and test it. To get the next one, you use the algorithm from [Hamming weight based indexing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13542794/hamming-weight-based-indexing#answer-13614164) (it's C code, but should not be to hard to translate it to java).

Comment: That is a very usefull answer! I could find any concept and you bring me the "Hamming weight"... That was where I needed to look, Thank you! Now, I would like to find a better formulation for my question so that anyone who look for something like this could find it... If you have any idea, feel free to help me ;)

Comment: What about changing the subject to sth. like "Enumerating integers in increasing order of number of bits set"?

Answer (score 1):

Here's some code I put together some time ago to do this. Use the `combinadic` method giving it the number of digits you want, the number of bits you want and which number in the sequence.

```
// n = digits, k = weight, m = position.
public static BigInteger combinadic(int n, int k, BigInteger m) {
    BigInteger out = BigInteger.ZERO;
    for (; n > 0; n--) {
        BigInteger y = nChooseK(n - 1, k);
        if (m.compareTo(y) >= 0) {
            m = m.subtract(y);
            out = out.setBit(n - 1);
            k -= 1;
        }
    }
    return out;
}

// Algorithm borrowed (and tweaked) from: http://stackoverflow.com/a/15302448/823393
public static BigInteger nChooseK(int n, int k) {
    if (k > n) {
        return BigInteger.ZERO;
    }
    if (k <= 0 || k == n) {
        return BigInteger.ONE;
    }
    // ( n * ( nChooseK(n-1,k-1) ) ) / k;
    return BigInteger.valueOf(n).multiply(nChooseK(n - 1, k - 1)).divide(BigInteger.valueOf(k));
}

public void test() {
    System.out.println("Hello");
    BigInteger m = BigInteger.ZERO;
    for ( int i = 1; i < 10; i++ ) {
        BigInteger c = combinadic(5, 2, m);
        System.out.println("c["+m+"] = "+c.toString(2));
        m = m.add(BigInteger.ONE);
    }
}
```

Not sure how it matches up in efficiency with the other posts.