# Iterable and Iterator in java

Tags: java, iterator

Here is my understanding on significance of using `Iterable` and `Iterator` in pre 1.8 java.

1)

`java.util.AbstractList` is `Iterable` because it implements,

`Iterator<T> iterator();`, which is a contract for any class to be `Iterable`.

2)

`java.util.AbstractList` implements,

`Iterator<T> iterator();` by creating an instance level inner class,

```
private class Itr implements Iterator<E> { ... }
```

that implements `hasNext`, `next` and `remove` methods.

`private class ListItr extends Itr implements ListIterator<E>{..}` is just an extra facility over above iterator for `List` type implementations.

3)

Is this the only purpose of these two interfaces `Iterable` & `Iterator`, to  enable any object to be iterable? Please let me know, if there is any other purpose of these two interfaces?

Comment: What do you mean by `signify their existence`?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6863182/what-is-the-difference-between-iterator-and-iterable-and-how-to-use-them

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5836174/java-iterator-and-iterable

Comment: @Eran their existence of usage

Comment: You described how Iterable is implemented in AbstractList. Other than that, it's still not clear what you're asking.

Comment: @Eran Is the query clear now?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are right stating what these interfaces are used for. Indeed `Iterable` declares that the objects of a class implementing it may be iterated over, by providjng an `Iterator` specific to these objects. Having them is necessary because how exactly the object should be iterated depends on its internal implementation, and an `Iterator` is therefore specific to a given "collection" class.

Having said that, it is worth noting that although these interfaces are formally a part of Java Collections framework, they can be applied to other cases. Given an imaginary API to read CSV files for example, one can declare a `CsvFile` class to implement an `Iterable<List<String>>` and iterate over lines in a file with a dedicated `Iterator<List<String>>` which will read lines from the file one-by-one and split them into a `List` of `String`s to return it from `next()`.

Another important purpose of these interfaces is a language feature known as "for each" loop - only objects of a class implementing `Iterable` can be iterated with it. So, given an example from above about `CsvFile` API, it will also enable something like:

```
CsvFile csvFile = new CsvFile(pathToCsvFile);
for (List<String> record : csvFile) {
    doSomethingWithIt(record);
}
```

As "for each" loop is purely a language feature, compiler will expand it to use an `Iterator` as usual.

P.S. Just because it hurts my eyes, I'd like to add that in the example above I would also suggest implementing an `AutoCloseable` for the `CsvFile` and using it with try-with-resources.

Comment: `java.util.ServiceLoader` is a real life example of a class implementing `Iterable` without being a `Collection`.

Answer (score 0):

java.util.Collection interface extends to java.util.Iterable. Iterable has a method that produces the iterator. If any class implements iterable, it has an iterator method that produces java.util.Iterator.

Please refer to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6863182/what-is-the-difference-between-iterator-and-iterable-and-how-to-use-them)

Comment: I don't think OP is asking about this implementation, instead asking any other use case other then this.

Answer (score 0):

If you check out interface Iterable it has only one method that is `Iterator<T> iterator();`. So there is **no other possible use case** for implementing Iterable interface other than providing iterator method.

If you see the documentation of **[Iterator](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Iterator.html)** interface, in **See Also** section you will find **[Collection](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collection.html), [ListIterator](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ListIterator.html), [Iterable](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Iterable.html)**. Collection and ListIterator are by default Iterable as they internally extend Iterable. So Iterable is used in conjunction with Iterator.

Comment: Another points is, Behavior responsibility is divided between `Iterable` and `Iterator` interface.  Can't single interface something like `Iterable`(say)  hold the responsibility having all 4 methods `hasNext` `next` `remove` and `iterator`? I mean, am not getting the thought process for having two interfaces, `Iterable` and `Iterator` instead of one. What is the thought process in designing this way?

Comment: It is just code division. You can see Iterator is used with Iterable and other interface extends Iterable only, so the functionality is kept directly on Interable.

Comment: And also Iterator is independent of Iterable. So the functionality is divided. Iterable's functionality is to provide iterator Object, and iterator's functionality is to provide next, remove, hasNext functions.

Comment: other interface, you mean, `interface Collection implements Iterable`? yes, but inner class of `AbstractList` which is `Itr`, has to implement `Iterator` to make it complete.

Comment: Yes because you want outside world to use Iterator functionality also you want to hide the implementation into inner class. Consider everyone using there own method names, it would create a mess, so they are implementing Iterator to implement their logic as well as giving freedom of using directly as Iterator object instead Itr object.

Comment: My point is, they could have placed all the method names in `Iterable`, instead of creating another interface `Iterator`.

Comment: If both of them are dependent on each other then it can be done. But in this case Iterable is dependent on Iterator, but Iterator is independent of Iterable. You will not see any use of iterable in iterator interface. And this is the choice of the coder of this interfaces.